# How to synchronize systemd stop order from one service?

Tags: systemd

Suppose I have `a.service` which I cannot modify, and `b.service` which I can modify, I want to see this stop order:

```
Stopping b.service ...
Stopped b.service
Stopping a.service ...
Stopped a.service
```

instead of this:

```
Stopping b.service ...
Stopping a.service ...
Stopped b.service
Stopped a.service
```

Assume that `b.service` may take at least 20 seconds to finish.

Comment: Related - https://serverfault.com/questions/785127/how-to-stop-systemd-services-in-specific-order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to stop `b.service` before `a.service`, you need to actually order `b.service` *after* `a.service`, since the ordering at service stop time is the inverse of the order at start time.

So this should be enough to accomplish what you described:

```
# b.service unit file
[Unit]
Description=...
After=a.service

[Service]
...
```

See the [documentation for `After=` in `man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=), which states:

> Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied. i.e. if a unit is configured with `After=` on another unit, the former is stopped before the latter if both are shut down.

You also asked about what happens if `b.service` takes at least 20 seconds to terminate. That is fine. If `b.service` is properly configured so systemd is able to monitor it until unit stop is completed (in other words, if `ExecStop=` is not somehow misconfigured) and if it stops before the timeout is reached (see [`TimeoutStopSec=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStopSec=)), then systemd will wait until `b.service` is fully stopped before initializing shutdown of `a.service`.

Comment: Oh I think I got confused because I saw `Stopped Qubes DB agent.`(as `a.service`) right after `Stopped Qubes Dom0 startup setup`(as `b.service`) and I assumed there should've been a `Stopping Qubes DB agent...` inbetween, but there wasn't because `Qubes DB agent` service is lacking any `ExecStop=` lines! So I thought the `Stopping` of `a.service` happened earlier than the `Stopped` for `b.service` which I took to mean that it didn't wait for `b.service` to fully stop before trying to stop `a.service`. But I was wrong. Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: Looks like it sometimes doesn't work, or there's something else happening. I tried 3 consecutive boots since I added `dev-block-253:0.device` to my `After=` in `qubes-core.service` (and did a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` of course) and the 3rd boot acted as if I hadn't added that so the order wasn't respected! all details here: https://gist.github.com/constantoverride/61207ebf622263d25fb1e5b1f11d0148/9443ef0babe29b32622dd0f17a2435a9e0f1df92#gistcomment-2696607  (where `qubes-core.service` is just a page scroll above). I must be missing something, or is it a systemd bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to stop these in a given order you can invoke the call to `systemctl` like this:

```
 $ systemctl stop a.service && systemctl stop b.service
```

or

```
 $ systemctl stop a.service; systemctl stop b.service
```